# Update dynamic Spreadsheet 'database' from sheets with dynamic values

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got two questions:

1) Is this the most efficient way of doing what I want. I guess if theres a lot of variables it will be time consuming? I wan't to be able to change the order of the columns in Target Data over time and the order of the rows in Origin Data. The Origin Data will come from different Spreadsheets and each of them will generate/refer to the data in a row in Target Data.

2) The script works as supposed except for one little detail. If the Id isn't found in the Target Data - I wan't the missing Id (and the corresponding data in the row) to be added to the Target Data. And I simply can't figure out how to do this.

I've put in links below for an example of the Target Data database and for some Origin Data examples including one where the Id isn't yet created in the database.

```
function toSaesonMulti() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Origin Data');

  var dataRange = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  var ssSeason = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1oHR2Iz0cRayVaNISgzw7LA2rcFzuicDjH0C9ZO-QPK0');
  var s1 = ssSeason.getSheetByName('Target Data');
  var lastColumn = s1.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = s1.getLastRow();

  var dataRangeSeason = s1.getDataRange().getValues();  

   for(var r = 0; r < dataRange.length; r++){
     var header = dataRangeSeason[0].indexOf(dataRange[r][0]);

     //If a column header is missing append insert the header at the end of the sheet
     if(header === -1){
       s1.getRange(1, lastColumn+1).setValue(dataRange[r][0]);
       //Update the variables to include the newly created header
       var lastColumn = s1.getLastColumn();
       var dataRangeSeason = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
     }

     //Define the id to look for
     if(dataRange[r][0] === 'Id'){
       var id = dataRange[r][1];
     }

     //Look for the Id column
     for(var c = 0; c < lastColumn; c++){
       if (dataRangeSeason[0][c] === 'Id'){

         //Look for the row to update
         for (var x = 0 ; x < lastRow ; x++){
           if(dataRangeSeason[x][c] === id){

             for (var y = 0 ; y < lastColumn ; y++){

               //Update the the data in the row matching the same header
               if(dataRange[r][0] === dataRangeSeason[0][y]){
                 s1.getRange(x+1, y+1).setValue(dataRange[r][1]);

               }
             }             
           }
         }
       }               
     }    
   }
}
```

[Database - Target Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oHR2Iz0cRayVaNISgzw7LA2rcFzuicDjH0C9ZO-QPK0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Data - Origin Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oHR2Iz0cRayVaNISgzw7LA2rcFzuicDjH0C9ZO-QPK0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Data - Origin Data3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z6zidgfhZWtEZ92XIRbrE2cx2zOSye_GTVDUzUFz364/edit#gid=0)

[Data - Origin Data2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRtjle_YR-6X_xcl7yG8LRyUu9irNqhfWsDM0ACL8AI/edit#gid=0)

[Data - Origin Data Missing in Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HbF48occS0MvG_taLBrD326FlCd_uumZd2LuVDtXWeM/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you have managed to solve your problem to add the row.

First of all using spreadsheets as a database is not a great idea, there are multiple services that fits better. Even in the google ecosystem:

- [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)
- [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)

But saying that you want to stick to spreadsheets for some reason. Yo should try to have a more modular code, as right now everything looks very messy, and having a three nested for-loop is not helping with efficiency either.

When looking for the ID in a column you should be using the [`TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class, that would be much faster than iterating over it.

That would get rid of 1 for loop, but of course is a good chance that the other two can also be left out using the `TextFinder`, as it kind of it job.

This change will speed up your code and more important, will make it easier to follow and understand. You can also make every loop a function like, `checkingForId()`, `checkingForRow()`, `updateCell()`, etc.

---

Also it seems you are declaring variables more than one time. I'm not sure if that would cause some bugs but for sure is confusing. Try to declare variables only one time. For example:

```
    if(rowIndex < 0){
      s1.getRange(lastRow+1, headerIdColumn+1).setValue(idValue)
      var dataRangeSeason = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
      var lastRow = s1.getLastRow();
    }
```

In here you don't need to use the `var` keyword as the two variables (`dataRangeSeason` and `lastRow`) have been already declared before. Adding `var` will just lead to confusion for other people (or even you in the future) looking at this code.

Moreover all this block could be converted to a function for clarity.

---

Although I tried to give you some hints take into account that Stack Overflow is not the place to post your code for having it "inspected", or improved. There is another stack page called [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=apps+script) aimed to that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I didn't know about the Code Review but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that get's the job done. But I'm not convinced it's the best and fastes way. If you have any suggestions how to optimize it I'm all ears. Right now it takes 2,5 seconds to create/update a new row.

```
function toSaesonMulti2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Origin Data');

  var dataRange = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  var ssSeason = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1oHR2Iz0cRayVaNISgzw7LA2rcFzuicDjH0C9ZO-QPK0');
  var s1 = ssSeason.getSheetByName('Target Data');
  var lastColumn = s1.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = s1.getLastRow();

  var dataRangeSeason = s1.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Find the column of Id
  var headerIdColumn = dataRangeSeason[0].indexOf("Id");
  var ids = s1.getRange(1, headerIdColumn+1, lastRow,1).getValues().toString();

  for(var i = 0; i < s.getDataRange().getLastRow(); i++){
    if(dataRange[i][0] === "Id"){
      var idRow = i;
      var idValue = s.getRange(idRow+1,2).getValue();
    }
  }


  //Find the row in the target, if it's not there create it
  var rowIndex = ids.indexOf(idValue)  

    if(rowIndex < 0){
      s1.getRange(lastRow+1, headerIdColumn+1).setValue(idValue)
      var dataRangeSeason = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
      var lastRow = s1.getLastRow();
    }

    for(var r = 0; r < dataRange.length; r++){
      var header = dataRangeSeason[0].indexOf(dataRange[r][0]);

      //If a column header is missing append insert the header at the end of the sheet
      if(header === -1){
        s1.getRange(1, lastColumn+1).setValue(dataRange[r][0]);
        //Update the variables to include the newly created header
        var lastColumn = s1.getLastColumn();
        var dataRangeSeason = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
      }

      //Look for the row to update
      for (var x = 0 ; x < lastRow ; x++){
        if(dataRangeSeason[x][headerIdColumn] === idValue){

          for (var y = 0 ; y < lastColumn ; y++){

            if(dataRange[r][0] === dataRangeSeason[0][y]){
              s1.getRange(x+1, y+1).setValue(dataRange[r][1]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just updated to make the order of the Origin index dynamic/independent - and this put a second extra on top of the runtime.